# How to persist model for Python TextBlob?

Tags: python, textblob

## How to persist model results for next update later in TextBlob?

The documentation reference can be found here  https://github.com/sloria/TextBlob

I noticed the documentation specified how to update the training data but I did not see a method or way to save data from a last session.

**how to update:**
https://textblob.readthedocs.io/en/dev/classifiers.html#updating-classifiers-with-new-data

In particular I'm referring to classifying text. I do feel I am dumb in this particular topic as I always find it difficult to know where these training sessions are being persisted in any AI examples.

You don't want to run the whole thing again right? You want to start where you left off and keep improving it iteratively.

I want to do this:

1. If past training results exists, load them into the model
2. Update or run new training session
3. Save training session
4. Repeat at a later time as needed

Comment: I don't know the answer but in tensorflow there is: `tf.train.Saver.restore()` which Restores previously saved variables.

Comment: Yah, I almost want to use that but this library is like dumb easy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The models and training can be persisted using **pickling** and **unpickling**.

```
>>> from textblob.classifiers import NaiveBayesClassifier
>>> train = [('love the weather','pos'),('love the world','pos'),('horrible place','neg')]
>>> cl = NaiveBayesClassifier(train)
>>> [cl.prob_classify("love food").prob('pos'),cl.prob_classify("love food").prob('neg')]
[0.8590880780051973, 0.14091192199480246]
>>> import cPickle
>>> save_training = open('/tmp/save_training.pickle','wb')
>>> cPickle.dump(cl,save_training)  # SAVE TRAINED CLASSIFIER
>>> save_training.close()
>>> 
>>> load_training = open('/tmp/save_training.pickle','rb')
>>> new_cl = cPickle.load(load_training) # LOAD TRAINED CLASSIFIER
>>> [new_cl.prob_classify("love food").prob('pos'),new_cl.prob_classify("love food").prob('neg')]
[0.8590880780051973, 0.14091192199480246]
```

Comment: Thanks @DhruvPathak ! Your rep is warranted.

Comment: Do you think this library is sufficient for categorization beyond 2 classifications?

Comment: @JasonSebring It uses NaiveBayes, so if you want to use NaiveBayes classifier, it is sufficient for any number of labels. For other classifiers including NaiveBayes. or better  control over how your text is processed, would recommend scikit-learn.

Comment: Ya I tried that too on scikit but memory kept killing my machine :)